# How to create custom factors based on an existing factor model?

Tags: factor-models, risk-models

I'm searching some literatures or books illustrating how to create custom factors based on an existing factor model.

For example, given an existing Barra factor risk model, if I want to add some custom factors, say crowding style factor and Steel industry factor (assuming it's not already in the risk model), how do I start? In these cases, I'd like to use the factors provided by Barra with "piggy-backing" new custom factors.

Is there some papers/books/literatures illustrate how to do this? Feel this is pretty widely used already.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: I'm surprised if this approach is used widely because it seems like something you would want to do totally seperately  rather than view it "a supplement". There are assumptions regarding the barra risk factor model so, unless you had the A) ACTUAL CODE used at every step and B) the EXACT formulae for each of the factors, my thinking is that starting from scratch ( building a model from scratch ) is better than a piggy backing attempt. But that's just my opinion. Others may disagree.